# The linux's permission

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

Description:
I used root account login in,and create a file (only root can write & read)in other account(if user is test)home directory.issues comming,when i use test account login in ,use 'vim' & 'wq!' command unexpectedly can save success!!,what happen ?why?

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to understand your post. I'm really trying to, but I might interpret it wrongly:

1. You log in as **root** and create a file in **user test**'s home directory?
2. Then, you **log out from root** and **log in as test**?
3. Then, **as user test**, you **launch Vim** and issue command "**force write & quit**?
4. You are perplexed as to **why** you are allowed to **create a file** as **user test**, inside a directory **owned by user test**?

Comment: you are right, it's my question!Do you understand the cause of the problem ？

Comment: Well, if that is the question, I certainly have the answer:

There is no problem, because the user **test** is the owner of the directory of which he is creating a file in. In fact, this is the ideal behavior; we wouldn't want the other way around, would we?

Comment: You mean all users for their catalog file have permission to modify, regardless of the directory file owner and group?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. Have a look at [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm) to learn more of Unix ownership and permissions.